# Selecting a data from table while fetching the MAX value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**QUERY:**

I have a table consisting columns like UserId and FirstName

What i want to do is:

I want to fetch the FirstName while getting the max if UserId

My novice attempt:

```
select FirstName from tblUsers where MAX(UserId)=@UserId
```

Which is showing the error of:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

A query without @UserId is also welcome

Comment: Could you include sample data and the expected output? Although the answers below will do what you ask for, I'm not sure that's exactly what you want. A few demo records should help us sort this out.

Comment: Is UserID the primary key?

Comment: Impossible to tell what you are trying to acomplish

Comment: Yes, its PK and Bigint @jarlh

Comment: Can you help me with a query which will provide me the FirstName of the maximum UserId. That's all i request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `HAVING` in following:

```
select FirstName 
from tblUsers 
group by FirstName
having MAX(UserId)=@UserId
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to get only 1 `FirstName` which have highest `UserId` you can use `TOP 1` in following:

```
select top 1 FirstName
from tblUsers
order by UserId desc
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm not recommending to use this solution, but If you want (for any reason) to use `MAX(UserId)` you can do something like:

```
select FirstName
from tblUsers
group by FirstName
having max(UserId ) = (select max(UserId) from tblUsers)
```

Comment: @Arka not working is not enough. If you want to get correct answer you should provide more information. What not working? Are you getting an error? Incorrect results? Also provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Can you help me with a query which will provide me the FirstName of the maximum UserId. That's all i request.

Comment: The question is just an attempt to solve it.@Stanislovas

Comment: @Arka Check an updated answer. You could use `TOP 1`

Comment: It can be done, but better to use `TOP 1` updated an answer with solution.

Comment: The **UPDATE 1** is fine for me...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
select FirstName from tblUsers group by FirstName having MAX(UserId)=@UserId
```

HAVING is like a where clause for aggregate expressions.

But that doesn't seem to make sense to me.  You'll only get a row if @UserId is the maximum user Id in the table, so I don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: You have to use group by if you want to use having and also this is duplicate answer.

Comment: I want to have the firstname of the maximum UserId, in a single query

Comment: But @UserId might not have the max UserId - what's @ UserId for?  I think
    HAVING UserId = MAX(UserId)
is probably what you want, but I don't understand what @ UserId is for.

Comment: Can you help me with a query which will provide me the FirstName of the maximum UserId. That's all i request @AbeCrabtree

Comment: Then the first answer was after all what you wanted: "SELECT FirstName FROM tblUsers HAVING UserId = MAX(UserId)".  This works for me on Sybase but I'm not completely certain it's not using a Sybase Sql extension, so you'll need to try.

Comment: Henk's answer above would be standard sql - try that

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations are not supported in where clauses,since below is the logical querying phases

```
from
where
group by
having
select 
order by 
top
```

So in your case,SQL goes to your table and in where clause you asking result of  aggregation which is unknown at that point of time,since SQL knows only table columns in this stage...   since we use group by for aggregations,next operator having access to result of group by is having,so you have to refer any aggregations in having or using a derived table or a cte

Answer (score 0):

Agree with some others that you should try to be more explicit about what you want exactly. After reading your second comment on Stanislovas' answer I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM   tblUsers
WHERE  UserId =
      (SELECT MAX(UserId)
       FROM   tblUsers
      )
```

The subquery first selects the maximum UserId value, which is then used as value to select the corresponding FirstName.